# Scala List with cached length

Tags: list, scala, collections

For some algorithm I am operating on the same list (or suffixes thereof) over and over again and I am accessing the `length`. However, apart from that I only access `head` and `tail`, so I don't need random access. What is the best way to optimize access to the length?

Is the `length` already cached internally (maybe a `lazy val`?)? Should I write a wrapper around `List` or subclass it? Can I do it with a trait and would that be a good solution? Should I use another collection class like `Vector` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `List`, `length` and `size` are defined in `TraversableOnce` and `LinearSeqOptimized` which are shared by mutable collections, so they cannot be cached. If you search the standard library source for `val length` or `val size`, there are no collection class members that appear.

You can't sub-class `List`, because it is `sealed`, but you can wrap it if you like. More work would be necessary to allow things like `map`, etc, while also preserving the size.

```
case class WrappedList[A](list: List[A]) {
    lazy val length = list.length
}
```

`Vector` appears to be a decent option. `length` isn't *strictly* cached, but it is defined as:

```
def length = endIndex - startIndex
```

Where `endIndex` and `startIndex` are private constructor vals, making it much faster than `List#length`. Without seeing the algorithm in question, it is difficult to make further recommendations about which collection type to use.